# What would be overhead times for an AWSIOT Pubsub model?

Tags: amazon-web-services, mqtt, aws-iot

My application is using AWS IOT with an MQTT protocol. I have not scaled it yet. On what would the time for communication between AWS Broker and Enddevice depend on, for 1 million users?

Comment: Why do you think it would be dependent on the number of users and not say the network between the device and the cloud?

Comment: There are too many variables: network infrastructure characteristics, message payload frequency / size / format / encryption, endpoint characteristics (device, back-office) to do any kind of prediction. You will not get away without some kind of empirical testing: https://gambitcomm.blogspot.com/2018/12/how-to-test-accuracy-of-your-iot.html

Comment: Thank you Gambit support, this is exactly what I was confused about.